# Can I have two aspx pages share the same code-behind file?

Tags: asp.net, code-behind, ab-testing

For split testing, I have three pages which do exactly the same thing but look visually very different (significant changes to both HTML and CSS).

Is there a way I can create two or more ASPX pages which use exactly the same code behind? Whatever I try doesn't seem to work due to how aspx pages are compiled. Ideally I'd live to have page1.aspx, page2.aspx both have Inherits="*CommonClassName*"  but then I just can't get it to compile.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new class which inherit from Page

```
public class ParentPage : System.Web.UI.Page
```

in there put whatever you want to share.  then have your pages inherit from there:

```
public partial class PageFirst : ParentPage 
public partial class PageSecond : ParentPage
```

Comment: I've tried this solution but it can't see any of the page controls on the page from the base class so I don't see a practical way of using this method given the number of controls on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Put your common logic into utility classes that all three visually different pages can call to exercise that functionality.

For example,

```
public static bool SaveValueToDatabase(string theValue)
{
    // Call database from here
}
```

Now in your three pages, you can invoke this shared logic, like this:

```
var success = SaveUserToDatabase(TextBox1.Text);

if(!success)
{
    // Alert user of failure
}
```